# Jquery, how to attribute two or more input name and change its value

Tags: jquery, attr, each

Please I have the following markup :

```
<div class="closet">
   <input name="hello1" class="input" />
</div>


<div class="closet">
   <input  name="hello2" class="input" />
</div>
```

and I want to attribute the input name and set another value (example hello5 and hello6) , so this is my code :

```
var i = 5;
$('.closet').each(function (k) 
{
    i++;

   $('.input').attr('name', 'hello'+i);
});
```

But the problem it gave me for both inputs the value "hello6".

Please have you any advise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
$('.input').attr('name', 'hello'+i);
```

with

```
$('.input', this).attr('name', 'hello'+i);
```

so to change the `.input` that is inside the `.closet` on which your iteration is.

Answer (score 0):

You already have access to both an index and the element inside the `each()` loop:

```
$('.closet').each(function(index, elem)  {
   $('.input', elem).attr('name', 'hello'+(index+5));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('.input').attr('name', 'hello'+i);
```

Should be

```
$(this).find('.input').attr('name', 'hello'+i);
```